# How can I access a file that's part of the deployment in an Azure Webrole

Tags: c#, azure, file-io, azure-web-roles

We have a WCF service that we deploy to our customers servers, and we're now creating a webrole that will enable us to run the same service on Azure.
The trouble is that the service project has an img-folder where we store a couple of images used when files are missing or as logo. When our service try to acccess this file with this line of code

```
File.Open(StoragePath, FileMode.Open);
```

we get the following exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'E:\sitesroot\0\bin\img\delficertwarning.tif' is denied.
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: What user does the code that is denied access run?

Comment: We haven't tried other than the default user of an Azure Webrole, especially not since we found the solution with using only read access.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you have to specify that you're only going to use the opened file for reading:

```
File.Open(StoragePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```